Adjust grid gap of other items if an item reaches to its max-width
Evenly spacing for box 2 and 3 works fine when they reach to their max-width because they reach first. But box 1 and 4 still waits to reach to their max-width.
This leads to a weird looking gap spacing while resizing. Is there any workaround to start adjusting gap spacing evenly after any of the items starts to auto adjust itself? (in this case 2 and 3)
So the desired result would be, if boxes are smaller than 150px, keep 10px gap. Whenever any of them reach to 150px, keep the spacing on both ends but begin to open the gap between boxes evenly.


.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  height: 100%;
  grid-template-columns: 15% 25% 25% 15%;
  gap: 10px;
  background-color: #2196F3;
  padding: 10px;
  justify-content: center;
  align-content: space-evenly;
}

.grid-container>div {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
  text-align: center;
  padding: 20px 0;
  font-size: 30px;
  max-width: 150px;
}
<div class="grid-container">
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
  <div>4</div>
</div>



Edit:


Thank you for adding the further detail that the spaces at the ends must remain constant. I believe this constraint means that you will need JavaScript so that this space can be calculated. I will leave my initial answer up for a short while in case it helps someone bring in this extra constraint.

The grid seems happier if you tell it explicitly that there is a maximum width.
This snippet does this by setting min(15%, 150px) and min(25%, 150px) in the grid-template-columns property rather than setting the max-width on the individual children.


.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  height: 100%;
  grid-template-columns: min(15%, 150px) min(25%, 150px) min(25%, 150px) min(15%, 150px);
  gap: 10px;
  background-color: #2196F3;
  padding: 10px;
  justify-content: center;
  align-content: space-evenly;
}

.grid-container>div {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
  text-align: center;
  padding: 20px 0;
  font-size: 30px;
  max-width: 150px;
}
<div class="grid-container">
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
  <div>4</div>
</div>




Thanks for the answer. Yes, I want to align them centrally but also I want to distribute the gap space evenly. I've added a diagram that shows the desired result.

That's what the snippet does - is there something it's not achieving that you want?

Sort of.. I don't know how to explain without showing. I am using Chrome. In my browser, your solution leaves spacing from beginning and from end. It keeps 10px gap spacing. I need just the opposite. I want to keep the spacing from the beginning and the end, then evenly distribute the space between boxes.

So why are you specifying gap size?

Because I want 10px gap until they reach to their max. width

And then what do you want to happen?

Keep the spacing on both ends of containet fixed. If boxes are smaller than 150px, keep 10px gap.  If they reach to 150px, keep the space on both ends still fixed but open the gap between boxes evenly.

Ah, so you can’t use center and gap the same way. Please put this constraint in your question as it makes a difference. I will delete this answer when you’ve done that, thanks.

I appended the constraint to the end of the question per your request.
